# TableView row height shrinks when I am trying to reorder row using tableView(moveRowAt:)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using custom tableViewCell as follows to populate my tableView

```
1. title = UILabel()
2. subtitle = UITextView()
3. count = UILabel()
```

These are all setup programmatically using `autoLayoutConstraints`.

I then populated tableView defined in my main `viewController` as a `tableView datasource` and `tableView delegate`. So all the `tableView` related setup is happening in my main viewController.

I am using `automaticDimension` to set the `rowHeight` of the `tableView`.

Problem is,

When I use func `tableView(moveRowAt:)` to reorder my `tableView` rows, the row height shrinks or collapses as I drag my selected `tableView` row to another `indexPath`.

How can I solve this problem?

In class `MainViewController: UIViewController`,

```
    lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView()
        tv.delegate = self
        tv.dataSource = self
        tv.separatorStyle = .none
        tv.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tv.backgroundColor = nil
        tv.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
        tv.allowsSelection = true
        tv.estimatedRowHeight = 70
        return tv
    }()
```

Comment: The row is reduced to a height equal to estimatedRowHeight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was I added this line of code in my CustomCell.swift

```swift
    override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set (newFrame) {
            var frame =  newFrame
            frame.origin.y += 4
            frame.size.height -= 6
            super.frame = frame
        }
    }
```

this line of code adds a spacing between rows, but it somehow interferes with the row height when tried to move rows in editing mode.

this must be removed and refactored to a more suitable code in order to implement proper spacing between rows.

Answer (score 0):

u can use this code for moveRowAt indexpath function

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {


    var animals = ["Dog","Cat","Mouse","hen"]
    var numbers = ["1","2","3","4"]
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.isEditing = true
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160
        // tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
        //tableView.allowsSelection = true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return animals.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.animalOne.text = animals[indexPath.row]
        cell.NumberOne.text = numbers[indexPath.row]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let moveobject = self.animals[sourceIndexPath.row]
        animals.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        animals.insert(moveobject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }

}
```

in table viewcell

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var animalOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var NumberOne: UILabel!
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this wasn't my question